# Android Wear Watchface needs to access the internet

Tags: android

I'm working on a watchface which needs to access the internet. I know wearables can't access the internet directly and I need to somehow use the GoogleApiClient to communicate with a handheld app which handles the web requests but I can't seem to find any samples or examples of how to actually do it.

Could somebody point me to some sample projects for communicating between handheld and wearable apps? I have most of the information I need to do it myself but the problem is, I haven't the slightest idea of how to piece everything together.

Answer (score 0):

After much Googling, I found a great little sample that helped me get communications happening! For anybody having the same difficulties, check out this sample: https://github.com/petrnalevka/wear